# strange incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c++

I have this strange error in my function. I know it's a pointer error, but i can't understand what it's.

My code :

```
int Minimum(double histogram[] )
{
    int iter =0;
    int threshold = -1;
    double iHisto[256];

    for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
        iHisto[i]=(double) histogram[i];

    double *tHisto = iHisto;

    while (!bimodalTest(iHisto))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
            tHisto[i] = (iHisto[i - 1] + iHisto[i] + iHisto[i + 1])/3;
            }
            tHisto[0] = (iHisto[0] + iHisto[1]) / 3; //0 outside
            tHisto[255] = (iHisto[254] + iHisto[255]) / 3; //0 outside
            iHisto = tHisto;//Her is the line where i have the error
            iter++;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            if (iHisto[i - 1] > iHisto[i] && iHisto[i + 1] >= iHisto[i])
            {
                threshold = i;
                break;
            }
        }
return threshold;
```

}

Any help please!!!

Comment: `iHisto` is no pointer, but an array

Comment: `I have this strange error in my function.` And the error is... ? My crystal ball is cloudy lately, I have difficulty reading the text on your monitor.

Comment: @Ben Chaaben Assil Point out the statement that produces the error and the error message

Comment: Arrays can't be re-assigned. If you want an array with value semantics, use `std::array`. If you want to work with memory you allocate and swap pointers or whatever, remember that arrays aren't pointers.

Comment: So how should i do it?

Comment: `iHisto = tHisto;` Why do you want to do this? What is this supposed to achieve? Realize that you were modifying `iHisto` all this time: with `double *tHisto = iHisto;`, `tHisto` is simply an alias for `iHisto`, accessing the same block of memory. You seem to believe this makes a deep copy of all the values in the array - it doesn't. When you write `tHisto[i] = something;`, it has exactly the same effect as `iHisto[i] = something;`

Comment: well i'm trying to convert from a java code in the java code i have this line :             double [] tHisto = iHisto;                                                                                                             iHisto = tHisto;                                                                                                so what is the rquivalent in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the contents of an array to another using memcpy.

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Answer (score 0):

An array variable cannot used on the LHS of an assignment operator. In other words, the value of an array variable cannot be changed, it can only be initialized. You can change the elements of the array but not the array.

It's not clear to me what you hope to accomplish in the line

```
iHisto = tHisto;
```

You certainly don't need to copy the contents. `tHisto` is initialized to point to the first element of `iHisto`. The elements of `iHisto` can be accessed through `iHisto` as well as `tHisto`.